# why is my perl system command not working?

Tags: linux, perl

This is my perl code to move result to the sent folder.

```
 system("mv /home/pi/downloads/$result /home/pi/downloads/sent/$result");
```

The error i get is:

```
mv: missing destination file operand after `/home/pi/downloads/filename.txt'
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's difficult to say but there's a few things you can do that should help you solve it.

First make sure your script starts like this:

```
#!/pathe/to/perl -w

use strict;
```

Notice the -w to enable warnings. Also `use strict` will help you identify code issues.

Another thing that helps a lot is storing the command you want to run in a scalar and printing it to see what it is actually doing:

```
my $result = "filename.txt";
chomp($result);
my $cmd = sprintf("mv /home/pi/downloads/%s /home/pi/downloads/sent/%s", $result, $result);
print "$cmd\n";
system($cmd);
```

In your script do you get the value for $result from user input? I have a feeling it has a newline character. The chomp function will safely remove newline characters from the end of a string.

Comment: this got me on the right track. thanks! I ended up needing $result =~ s/\n//g;

Comment: @BluGeni uh, bad `\n` symbol, hate it at the end of line :\

Comment: Note that using this code you will never know if your `mv` command has failed for any reason - like lack of permissions, wrong filename, etc...

Answer (score 8):

Most likely `$result` contains a newline, which prematurely terminates the command. Use `chomp` to discard the extra newline.

If `$result` comes from user input and it wasn't chomped, there's almost certainly a newline character. And, depending on the audience for your program, you now have a malicious code injection problem.

To avoid the injection problem, how about using the `rename` function to move the file into the destination?

Answer (score 3):

While you can call external programs to do something for you using `system()` or `qx{}`, Perl is extremely powerful and versatile, and for many common operations it can be done using just Perl itself (or its numerous modules), without using anything external. It is both faster and more reliable if any problems with external programs arise. For example, if external executable is buggy and spins in tight loop, `system()` may never return, freezing your script.

In your case, this Perl code works better AND handles errors:

```
use File::Copy;

unless (move ("/home/pi/downloads/$result",
              "/home/pi/downloads/sent/$result"))
{
    print "Rename has failed!\n";
    # ...
}
```

(Of course, you should make sure that `$result` does not contain newlines before you run this.)

Answer (score 1):

Check both `$result` and the directories themselves:

- Make sure `$result` doesn't have **slashes** in it (unless  you're expecting subdirectories)
- Make sure `$result` doesn't have **spaces** in it since the command doesn't use quoting
- Make sure `$result` isn't empty

For the directories:

- Make sure `/home/pi/downloads` exists and is a directory
- Make sure `/home/pi/downloads/sent` exists and is a directory
- Make sure `/home/pi/downloads` has writable permissions
- Make sure `/home/pi/downloads/sent` has writable permissions